# Automatic int to float conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

```
m = 10
x = 5
val = 1
print(type(val))
for i in range(1, x+1):
    val = (val * (m + i)) / (i)
    print(type(val))
    print(val)
```

Here initially `val` is of type `int` but in the loop it is getting converted to `float` although I am performing integer by integer division. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use: `//`

```
val = (val * (m + i)) // (i)
```

And your val will remain being an integer

The behavior of `/` was changed with this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

The `operator` module docs give also a hint about the separation between `true division` (returning a float) and `floor division` which returns the floor and therefore an `int`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: might be useful to add that this changed between python2 and python3 in your answer

Answer (score 2):

It is specified in the *Semantics for True division* in **[`PEP 238`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)**:

> True division for `int`s and `long`s **will convert the arguments to
>     `float`** and then apply a `float` division.  That is, even `2/1` will
>     return a `float` (`2.0`), not an `int`.  For `float`s and `complex`, it       will be the same as classic division.

So an automatic conversion is performed when an `int` is found. Note that this is the default behaviour in Python 3. In python 2 you'll need to `import` from `__future__` in order to have similar results.